# Wordpress function to update or create robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, function, robots.txt

I am making a plugin for Wordpress with a function to update the file robots.txt or to create it if not existing yet.

So far I have this function:

```
function roots_robots() {

  echo "Disallow: /cgi-bin\n";
  echo "Disallow: /wp-admin\n";
  echo "Disallow: /wp-includes\n";
  echo "Disallow: /wp-content/plugins\n";
  echo "Disallow: /plugins\n";
  echo "Disallow: /wp-content/cache\n";
  echo "Disallow: /wp-content/themes\n";
  echo "Disallow: /trackback\n";
  echo "Disallow: /feed\n";
  echo "Disallow: /comments\n";
  echo "Disallow: /category/*/*\n";
  echo "Disallow: */trackback\n";
  echo "Disallow: */feed\n";
  echo "Disallow: */comments\n";
  echo "Disallow: /*?*\n";
  echo "Disallow: /*?\n";
  echo "Allow: /wp-content/uploads\n";
  echo "Allow: /assets\n";
  echo "\n";
}

add_action('do_robots', 'roots_robots');
```

The file robots.txt is not updating, did I forget anything?
Also is there a way to check first if existing and if not creating the file?

I found something from the plugin kb-robots but I'm not 100% sure how to add it to my function..

```
function kb_robotstxt(){
    # this is to make it work for demos and testing. Without this, plugin would only act when robots.txt is in a valid place. With this, it will act whenever robots.txt is appended to blog URL
    # (even if blog is in a subdirectory)
    $request = str_replace( get_bloginfo('url'), '', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

    if ( (get_bloginfo('url').'/robots.txt' != 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && ('/robots.txt' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && ('robots.txt' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )
        return;     // checking whether they're requesting robots.txt

    $robotstxt = get_option('kb_robotstxt');

    if ( !$robotstxt)
        return;

    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    print $robotstxt;
    die;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should save the data to the file, not output it to the browser. Check out [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents). You must also make sure that the file is writable by the web server.